# jQuery Scroll doesn't work in IE 7 and IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Here is an example of what I use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    console.log('scroll');

    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        console.log('scrolling 1');
    });

    jQuery(document).scroll(function () {
        console.log('scrolling 2');
    });
});
```

This will only return "scroll in IE 7 and IE 8.
And in Chrome, Firefox and IE 9 it will return everything one time and "scrolling 2" whenever I'm scrolling.

I am also locked to jQuery 1.3

Does anyone have any idea how to get this working in IE 7 and IE 8?

---

Edit:
I have now found out that the reason of this seems to relate to a [jQuery Lightbox Plugin](http://pastie.org/3130251).

Comment: As I recall you can give the body relative positioning or something like that to make it work. Sorry I don't have time to sort it for you!

Comment: It seems like the problem is not the code it self but some other script that is interfering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was on row 817 in [jquery.lightbox.js](http://pastie.org/3130251)

```
$(window).unbind().resize(function ()
```

This will unbind everything connected to $(window) and not only resize.
So the solution is:

```
$(window).unbind('resize').resize(function ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the ScrollTo plug-in.

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Their demo page uses jQuery 1.3.2 -

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Also note:

> Doesn't scroll on IE.  Sometimes, you need to set a position (relative or absolute) to the container and give it fixed dimensions, in order to hide the overflow.
>   If this doesn't work, try giving the container fixed dimensions (height & width).

UPDATED
Using jQuery 1.11.1, using [jquery.scrollTo release 1.4.13](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/releases/tag/1.4.13) with the following:

```
$( '#parent' ).scrollTo( $( '#target' ), 800 );
```

This works on IE 7.0.5730.11.

Comment: The thing I'm doing is a menu that is fixed to the top of the screen depending on where the user has scrolled. But as I wrote in the comment above, I don't think the problem is the code or the markup but another script that is failing or something like that.