# jQuery scroll event not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

As the following works on all browsers except Internet Explorer 7, which I need it to work on mainly,

`$( window ).scroll(function() {
  alert("Hello");
})`

http://jsfiddle.net/zrEFU/

Is there any way that this could be implemented myself? Not too sure on how to go about it. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Some references from here and the rest of internet, as I also want to find a solution to this;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881008/jquery-window-scroll-and-internet-explorer-8-9
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725536/jquery-scroll-doesnt-work-in-ie-7-and-ie-8
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/make-window-scroll-work-in-ie

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use jQuery 1.x since that version will keep x-browser support.
If you use jQuery 2.x you will loose x-browser support.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/Pp67n/) jQuery 1.11.0 => IE6,7,8 support YES

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/Pp67n/3/) jQuery 2.x(edge) => IE6,7,8 support NO

*In return, jQuery 2.x is smaller, faster, and can be used in JavaScript environments where the code needed for old-IE compatibility often causes problems of its own.*

Answer (score -1):

I usually prefer to use a timer instead of scroll events. I haven't tried on IE7 though.

I would do something like so:

```
var topy = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() !== topy) {
        topy = $(window).scrollTop();

        // whatever you need to do...

    }
},200);
```

Comment: that doesn't work on IE7 and repeatedly executes the "whatever you need to do part" in Chrome

Comment: Sorry about that, there was a name conflict for variable 'top'.